# Functional test for log-in in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

How do I allow my test to authenticate as a (FOSUserBundle) user?

```
const USER_INDEX_PATH = '/users';

public function testIndex()
{
    $client = parent::createTestClient();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', self::USER_INDEX_PATH);

    $administrator = UserData::newAdminUser();
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Login')->form();

    $form['_username'] = $administrator['username'];
    $form['_password'] = $administrator['password'];

    $client->submit($form);
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();

    $this->assertEquals(
        1,
        $crawler->filter('h1:contains("Users")')->count(),
        "NOT FOUND"
    );
}
```

When I run that I get: `LogicException : The request was not redirected.`
If I remove the `followRedirect()` that doesn't fix it either.

What am I doing wrong? If I do a `print_r($crawler);` after the form is submitted I still see  `[uri:protected] => http://myproject.local/login` so it doesn't appear to be submitting the form?

## Update:

Fixed it by changing the submit line to `$crawler = $client->submit($form);`
Then it worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi there. All sorted so! :) If you find a solution, you can answer your own questions. You should submit your update as an answer, and also mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the submit line to `$crawler = $client->submit($form);` Then it worked perfectly.